# Show that $R$ has a pmf defined over the positive rationals

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a probability mass function given by

$$P(R=r)=\frac{(e-1)^2}{e^{m+n}-1},$$

where $r$ is a rational number of the form $\frac{m}{n}$ where gcd$(m,n)=1$.

I need to show that $\sum_{r \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}} P(R=r)=1$.

See that tuples of the form $(1,m),(m,1)$ are contributing to the sum trivially. But there are so many pairs $(m,n)$ which satisfy the property that $(m,n)=1$, how can I sum this over all such pairs?
Is there any other way?

Comment: This should answer your question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103969/constructing-a-discrete-r-v-having-as-support-all-the-rationals-in-0-1

Comment: Nope doesn't help much :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to show that:

$$\sum_{(m,n) \in Q^+} \frac{(e-1)^2}{ e^{(m+n)}  - 1 } = 1$$

We note that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k(m+n)} = \frac{e^{-(m+n)}}{1 - e^{-(m+n)}} = \frac{1}{ e^{(m+n)}  - 1  
}$$

so, we can write

$$\sum_{(m,n) \in Q^+} \frac{(e-1)^2}{ e^{(m+n)}  - 1 } = (e-1)^2 \sum_{(m,n) \in Q^+} \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k(m+n)} $$

However,

$$\sum_{(m,n) \in Q^+} \sum_{k=1}^\infty = \sum_{(km, kn) \in N \times N} $$ since each element $(km,kn)$ is counted once in both sides of the sum, and since all summands are positive, reordering is allowed. Letting $a = km, b = kn$ we finally have that

$$\sum_{(m,n) \in Q^+} \frac{(e-1)^2}{ e^{(m+n)}  - 1 } = (e-1)^2 \sum_{a,b \in N \times N} e^{-(a+b)} = (e-1)^2 \sum_a e^{-a} \frac{e^{-1}}{1 - e^{-1}} = \frac{(e-1)^2}{(e-1)^2} = 1$$